# The specified query is too complex to be evaluated as a single statement

Tags: javascript, powerbi

I am developing an advanced search custom visual that creates a list of multi select filters based on the categories that the user drags into the visual. Unfortunately, the way that selection manager works creating ids is that it appears to create the ids for the lowest grain of all dimensions/categories added. So for instance, when I select not recommended category in the attached example, instead of selecting the one dimension, the selection manager performs hundreds of selects for the lowest grain of developer. If I choose a broad group for the select, I receive the error: The specified query is too complex to be evaluated as a single statement

[image]

The gist of the current version of my visual is here:

https://gist.github.com/jcbowyer/5df55d4758a7614ca08d71eaf640fc57

How can I resolve this error and support large numbers of dimensions/combinations?

Comment: If you were using the generic slicer for this, each field would go into a separate slicer visual.  All the visuals on a report page cross-filter each other by default, and the performance is very good.  Perhaps this would be an easier approach for your project?

Comment: Currently, it looks like we are going with a non power bi approach/custom app dev but I am holding out hope that we can customize power bi.  There are various reasons such as the popup size and screen real estate when I need 10 or more slicers that the generic ones are not feasible.   I also have a second version that uses SelectionId.createWithIds that seems to get around this problem, but for some reason the createwithids does not work when I have multiple slicers.   I have logged a support ticket with ms and crossing my fingers there some paid support option.

Comment: Actually I didn't mean to use the generic slicers, I meant to try using separate instances of your search visual on a page (one for each field) as opposed to trying to use multiple fields in one visual.

Comment: Yes, I understood but was unclear in my response.  The issue is each slider takes up space for the popup and there is not enough room for the popups.  My current approach does permit dragging multiple instance of the slicer on the screen but.. there is not enough real estate for the popups with that approach.  It is frustrating because I am virtually certain what I want to do is possible and even possibly easy if I knew the correct syntax.